# I'm attempting to download a document using VBA, which appears to work, but the pdf does not show in Adobe Reader

Tags: vba, ms-access, docusignapi

I have recreated most of the API examples (Curl) in VBA to ensure I could successfully integrate DocuSign into Access 2010. My last task is to download a "completed" document and display it using Adobe Reader. I sent a DocuSign example document to myself and signed it. I then downloaded the document, which was successful (status = 200), and saved the text as a pdf file. But when I open it, a blank page appears. Reader shows an error message indicating "at least one signature is invalid".

The URL is:
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/10...4/envelopes/6ab....63b/documents/1?combined=false

VBA code:

```
`objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL & strURLExt, False`
`objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type: ", "application/pdf"`
`objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept: ", "application/pdf"`
`objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization: ", "Bearer " & strBearer`
`objHTTP.send`
```

I tried suggestions from other questions/recommendations, but none have resolved the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you click the link in your example above, it shows an error message, not a download for a PDF file unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche, the URL needs an access token. By design, it can't be used on its own.

Comment: You understand how that makes it kind of difficult for someone to take a look at your PDF and see what the problem is, yes? :)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Based on comments, I clearly need to read this site’s instructions on its use.  However, one response was the clue I needed to resolve the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

PDFs are usually binary files. So check that you're storing the file as a binary file. Seeing a blank page typically means the file was stored as a text file.